# Why won't toLowerCase convert the string element as lowercase?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Why won't this convert the string element as lowercase?
Given string input, converted into a string array. I want each word to be lowercase. However, when I debug, I notice the elements in my array are still varying in cases.

```
   String[] words = paragraph.split(" ");      //[how, to, do, in, java]
    for(String word : words){
        word = word.toLowerCase();
    }
```

Comment: It does, you're just not doing anything with the result.  `toLowerCase` will return a NEW object

Comment: If you were using older `for-loop` it would work better: `for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();`

Comment: For some languages, doing it the way you did would change word AND replace the old word object in the array with the new one.  Java does not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by doing `toLowerCase()`, you are instantiating a new `String`. So your `word` variable is no more a reference to an item of your array.

Either you add the result of the `toLowerCase()` to a new array or you loop with index :

```java
for(i = 0;i < words.size();i++) {
    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`toLowerCase` will return a `new` object, you have to store it.

You can use Java 8 to achieve it in one line:

```
Arrays.setAll(words, i -> words[i].toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying your array instead you are assigning the lowercase string to the word instance
You can use the classic for loop and assign the lowercase value to the current index of the array

for en example, your for loop should look like

```
for(int i=0;i< words.length;i++){
    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String objects are immutable by default. When you reassign something to string it creates a new object, hence the original String object in words array remain the same.